# Bash script: require each option parameter to occur at most once

Tags: regex, unix, duplicates

I am writing a script in unix, which will take options as parameter as shown:

```
./command -pers
```

The options allowed are `p`, `e`, `r`, `s` and can be in any order and are optional also. Example, these are correct syntax: `./command -e`, `./command -sr`, `./command -pes`, but this one is incorrect `./command -pep`, `./command -ssr`. Repetition of option is not allowed, but atleast one option is required.

For the same I have used regular expression, but it is not avoiding repetition.

But it is allowing repetition. Please tell what is wring with the expression.

```
[[ $1 =~ ^-[p{0,1}r{0,1}s{0,1}e{0,1}]{1,4}$ ]] || { echo "$MSG_INCORRECT_USAGE"; }
```

Comment: If you are writting a Bash script, you should probably abort your plan and parse your options with `getopts`, see `man bash`.

Comment: This isn't a problem that can be (elegantly) solved using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script `opt.sh` like this to **avoid processing each passed option more than once**:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "pers" opt; do
  [[ -n ${!opt} ]] && { echo "Error: $opt already processed"; exit 1; } || declare $opt=1

  case $opt in
    p) echo "processing p!" ;;
    e) echo "processing e!" ;;
    r) echo "processing r!" ;;
    s) echo "processing s!" ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" ;;
  esac
done
```

**Testing:**

```
bash ./opt.sh -srr
processing s!
processing r!
Error: r already processed

bash ./opt.sh -pep
processing p!
processing e!
Error: p already processed

bash ./opt.sh -pers
processing p!
processing e!
processing r!
processing s!
```

Comment: Planning to go with this approach `p_count=\`echo $1 | fold -w 1 | grep -c p\``, if any count > 1, then exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "pers" OPTION; do
        echo $OPTION
done
```

Results:

```
$ bash test.sh -pers
p
e
r
s
```

Replace `echo $OPTION` with a `case` statement and report errors if an option appears twice. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset OPT_P OPT_E OPT_R OPT_S

while getopts "pers" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
    p)
        if [ $OPT_P ]; then
            echo "-p appeared twice"
            exit 64
        else
            OPT_P="true"
        fi
        ;;
    #... and so on ...
    \?)
        echo "Unrecognized option $OPTION"
        exit 64
        ;;
done
```

Comment: Beware the user who runs: `OPT_P=1 ./command -pers` — or, in other words, make sure you set any variables that the script uses (and that should not be inherited from the parent process) to a known value — empty for the code shown — before running tests on the variables.

Comment: OK, I added an `unset`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arg0=$(basename $0 .sh)
error() { echo "$arg0: $*" >&2; exit 1; }
usage() { echo "Usage: $arg0 [-pers]" >&2; exit 1; }

p_flag=
e_flag=
r_flag=
s_flag=

while getopts pers arg
do
    case "$arg" in
    (e) [ -z "$e_flag" ] || error "-e flag repeated"
        e_flag=1;;
    (p) [ -z "$p_flag" ] || error "-p flag repeated"
        p_flag=1;;
    (r) [ -z "$r_flag" ] || error "-r flag repeated"
        r_flag=1;;
    (s) [ -z "$s_flag" ] || error "-s flag repeated"
        s_flag=1;;
    (*) usage;;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

[ -z "$e_flag$p_flag$r_flag$s_flag" ] && error "You must specify one of -e, -p, -r, -s"
[ $# = 0 ] || error "You may not specify any non-option arguments"

…process the code for each option that was set…
```

If you need to process the options in the sequence they're given, then you need to record the order in which they arrive.  Use an array:

```
flags=()
```

before the loop, and

```
flags+=("$arg")
```

after the `esac`.  The processing can then process each element of the `$flags` in sequence.

```
for flag in "${flags[@]}"
do
    …processing for the particular flag…
done
```